# Using (-) in fields

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm stuck on my application. I have named my table and fields name using ( `-` ) as glue instead of using ( `_` ). Since i love the `-` method i was figuring out how to keep it.
So i fixed my sql queries's table as follow:

First:

```
SELECT * FROM cool-table
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM `cool-table`
```

And it worked. But now with the fields name i don't really know hot to make this work:

```
SELECT * FROM `cool-table` WHERE cool-id = 1
```

The error i'm getting is related to the `-` of `cool-id`.
Any help?

**EDIT**

I swear i've tried to put

```
`cool-id`
```

but it seemed not to work for me. Now it does. So sorry for my stupid question.

Comment: Before you get too far in, just change your table/field names now while you can!

Comment: backticks will work for this everywhere, but i wouldnt recommend it.  this was a real pain in the ass when an ex-coworker decided to name a bunch of fields `desc`

Comment: @Charlie Please don't do it... `cool-id` means "cool minus id", and any trick to make it mean something different will only make future programmers hate you. So why don't you just change it to `cool_id`?

Comment: I'm with Daniel here, absolutely do rename them to something containing only letters, numbers, and underscores. Yes, it does look nicer and it works here, but I GUARANTEE you (from personal, painful experience) that many other applications won't play well with non-standard names.

Comment: Was the down-vote for my choice of using them? It's just stupid. I won't. It was just a legitimate question.

Comment: @Charlie - I upvoted to  counter for you.  that's a pretty stupid reason for a downvote.

Comment: @Charlie, I also dropped an upvote to counter the cranky person (or maybe just a slipped finger) who downvoted you.

Comment: @Larry, this things make me believe in a SO internal justice... Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do

```
 SELECT * FROM `cool-table` WHERE `cool-id` = 1
```

Note the single ticks (called identifier quotes, at least by me) added to the column name.

PS. This is a really bad idea, but you probably know that already.

Comment: @Charlie: Because you will have to quote these names absolutely EVERYWHERE, and anyone who works on the database will curse the day of your birth for doing this to them.

Comment: Well, you're already finding it difficult to write SQL against this database.  Imagine the next programmer who has to come along and support it.  Not only are you using a character that the engine really doesn't want you to use, you're using one that disguises intent — is that a column name?  Or a mathematical expression?

Comment: @Adam, well thanks for this answer. But i'm obsessed with avoiding `_` (underscore) because i seriously don't like them. I know this is stupid but i have a unserscore-phobia.

Comment: @Charlie, I don't like underscores either, in part because they are the default single character match in SQL.  I use initial capitals and no punctuation (eg `SELECT * FROM CoolTable WHERE CoolID = 1`).

Comment: I agree with Larry's naming convention.  Very clear IMO and avoids the issue you have with the -, AND it avoids underscores.

Comment: I will use your method. Thanks Larry.

Comment: @Charlie: Always a pleasure to be able to help someone out.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `cool-table` WHERE `cool-id` = 1
```

I'm pretty sure this should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to [use the backtick](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) just like you would for the table name, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `cool-table` WHERE `cool-id` = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Although MySQL allows hyphens in identifiers, standard SQL doesn't. By using hyphens, you pretty much guarantee that

1. a lot of applications simply won't work with your data,
2. you won't be able to move to another platform should you need to,
3. and anyone who uses your app will have to install MySQL.

Don't do it.